# Can I ask an advice for the algorithm of retrieving arrayList in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have a class in Java such like this

```
for (....) {
       tarik_id.add(id);
}
```

which is `tarik_id` is a `List<String>` and I want to add the `(id)` to be written in `tarik_id arrayList`. And then....

```
hasil = db.getDetailResult(tarik_id);
```

`getDetailResult` is a class for selecting all the `(id)` that I have pulled out with `tarik_id`.
And `hasil` is two dimensional table `(List.List.String..)`

I think that `tarik_id` doesn't return a value in my second line above. I have tried to Log.i my `id`, and the `LogCat` returns true values of my `id`. My question is how can the `tarik_id` in .`getDetailResult` returns all of the `array` values?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean =\

Comment: I agree with @LuiggiMendoza.A little more context in the variable names and also the overall purpose would help

Comment: first, I got an id variable. Then I want to add those ids into tarik_id which can be seen up above in loop(for). Then with procedure .getDetailResult, I want to select all of id that has been included in tarik_id and I want to make a new 2 dimensional table (hasil) that can wrap up all of the result of query. Any questions ?

Comment: From the code snippet there could be two reasons for this issue. First the condition for the loop. Make sure the for loop gets executed. Second they way you pass parameter to the procedure. Can you share that database call code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

make your code as the following:

```
// put the first id in first
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(id.get(0));
// start the loop from the 2nd
for (i=1; i < idList.size(); i++)
{
    stringBuilder.append(",").append(id.toString());
}
String ids = stringBuilder.toString()
hasil = db.getDetailResult(ids);
```

Change the code in `getDetailResult()` for the query to be something like

```
if(ids.equals("")){
      return null;
}
String sql = "SELECT * FROM...... WHERE ID IN("+ids+").....";
```

I think this is much faster, all records in 1 hit and no need for a second loop.